# Adding two decimal places

Tags: regex, r

I have a column in a dataset as shown below

```
            Col1
            ----------
            249
            250.8
            251.3
            250.33
            648
            1249Y4
            X569X3
            4459120  
            2502420
```

What I am trying to do is add two decimal places only to number that have only three digits , in other words, numbers that are in hundreds. For example, 249 should be converted to 249.00, 251.3 should be converted to 251.30 so on and not 4459120 or 2502420 or X569X3. The final output should look like this.

```
           Col1
            ----------
            249.00
            250.80
            251.30
            250.33
            648.00
            1249Y4
            X569X3
            4459120  
            2502420
```

I have looked at many different functions so far none of those work because there are some strings in between the numbers, for example X569X3 and seven digit numbers 2502420

---

Actual dataset

```
structure(c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 84L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 
102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 110L, 5L, 12L, 14L, 
16L, 20L, 24L, 36L, 40L, 44L, 48L, 52L, 56L, 83L, 85L, 75L, 112L, 
66L, 68L, 96L, 93L, 77L, 80L, 81L, 70L, 95L, 78L, 109L, 94L, 
63L, 67L, 98L, 73L, 79L, 76L, 90L, 111L, 69L, 97L, 64L, 92L, 
89L, 82L, 62L, 74L, 60L, 65L, 71L, 91L, 61L, 72L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 113L), .Label = c("1234X1", "123871", "1249Y4", "146724", 
"249", "249.01", "249.1", "249.11", "249.2", "249.21", "249.3", 
"249.4", "249.41", "249.5", "249.51", "249.6", "249.61", "249.7", 
"249.71", "249.8", "249.81", "249.9", "249.91", "250", "250.01", 
"250.02", "250.03", "250.1", "250.11", "250.12", "250.13", "250.22", 
"250.23", "250.32", "250.33", "250.4", "250.41", "250.42", "250.43", 
"250.5", "250.51", "250.52", "250.53", "250.6", "250.61", "250.62", 
"250.63", "250.7", "250.71", "250.72", "250.73", "250.8", "250.81", 
"250.82", "250.83", "250.9", "250.91", "250.92", "250.93", "2502110", 
"2502111", "2502112", "2502113", "2502114", "2502115", "2502210", 
"2502310", "2502410", "2502420", "2502510", "2502610", "2502611", 
"2502612", "2502613", "2502614", "2502615", "2506110", "2506120", 
"2506130", "2506140", "2506150", "2506160", "251.3", "251.8", 
"253.5", "258.1", "275.01", "277.39", "3640140", "3670110", "3670150", 
"3748210", "3774410", "3774420", "4459120", "5379670", "5379671", 
"6221340", "648", "648.01", "648.02", "648.03", "648.04", "648.8", 
"648.81", "648.82", "648.83", "648.84", "7079180", "775.1", "7821120", 
"7862120", "X569X3"), class = "factor")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your dataset to character:

```
x <- as.character(x)
```

Then perform the following:

```
ifelse(grepl("[[:alpha:]]", x) == FALSE & as.numeric(x) < 1000, 
                          sprintf("%.2f", as.numeric(x)), x)
```

Or if your data is in `Col1` in a dataframe:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Col1 = ifelse(grepl("[[:alpha:]]", Col1) == FALSE & as.numeric(as.character(Col1)) < 1000, 
                            sprintf("%.2f", as.numeric(as.character(Col1))), as.character(Col1)))
```

Comment: this worked , but for some reason I am getting a warning message, `Warning messages:
1: In ifelse(grepl("[[:alpha:]]", x) == FALSE & as.numeric(x) < 1000,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In sprintf("%.2f", as.numeric(x)) : NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: @TyVoss - it's a warning, not an error. R is just telling you that the `as.numeric` couldn't convert some of the options like `"1249Y4"` to a number, so `NA` was returned instead. It doesn't matter in the context of the rest of the operation.

Answer (score 4):

Let's call your vector `x`:

```
numbers = !is.na(as.numeric(x))
x.num = x[numbers]

x[numbers] = ifelse(as.numeric(x.num) < 1000,
       sprintf("%.2f", as.numeric(x.num)),
               x.num)
x

# [1] "249.00"  "250.80"  "251.30"  "250.33"  "648.00"
# [6] "1249Y4"  "X569X3"  "4459120" "2502420"
```

Comment: this didnt work everything turned into NA in the end. I have updated my question with the original data values above.

Comment: @TyVoss then just convert to character first, your data is probably factor.

Answer (score 3):

Use `formatC` with a selection of only the values you wish to replace.

```
x <- c("249", "250.8", "251.3", "250.33", "648", "1249Y4", "X569X3", "4459120", "2502420")
sel <- which(as.numeric(x) < 1000)
replace(x, sel, formatC(as.numeric(x[sel]), digits=2, format="f"))
#[1] "249.00"  "250.80"  "251.30"  "250.33"  "648.00"  "1249Y4"  "X569X3" 
#[8] "4459120" "2502420"
```

Comment: Huh, never saw the `replace` function before... guess I'll never stop learning new base utility functions.

Comment: @thelatemail, :( when i changed everything to numeric using the `as.numeric` function my entire data values got messy, everything changed to 1,2,3,....so on and the end result was NA. I have pasted a the actual dataset in my question above.

Comment: @TyVoss - Your data is a `factor` at the moment. Convert it using `as.character(df$Col1)` first before applying this code. This is why providing specific example data from the outset is always a good idea.

Comment: @thelatemail, after converting my column using `as.character(df$Col1)` i got all False at this step `which(as.numeric(df$Col1) < 1000)`

Comment: @TyVoss - I can't replicate that error using the data you provided. It works fine for me here. Maybe you need to start afresh with your data?